# Java - printf method - reduce field with

Tags: java, printf

I have a string `String dollar = "$"`. I want to print it out 5 times with the `System.out.printf()` method using a for loop such that each time, the width decreases by 1:

```
      $
     $
    $
   $
  $
```

The for loop would look something like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    System.out.printf("%5s", dollar);
}
```

How can I decrease the width of 5 by one every time the loop runs?

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--){
    System.out.printf("%" + i + "s\n", "$");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
  space = 5 - i;
  System.out.printf("%" + (5 - i) + "s", dollar);
}
```